# Update a RichTextBox on Sp2010 using Windows Forms & ListService.UpdateListItems Method

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, api, sharepoint

I'm having an issue updating a RichText box on a SharePoint 2010 list.

```
_batchElement.InnerXml =
            string.Format(
                "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field RichText='True' Name='Other_x0020_Items_x0020_of_x0020'>{0}</Field><Field Name='Overall_x0020_rating_x0020_of_x0'>{1}</Field><Field Name='Do_x0020_you_x0020_wish_x0020_to'>{2}</Field></Method>",
                add_Report_Details.Rtf,
                arrText,
                addreportwish);
```

And the code to trigger the update:

```
 ListService.UpdateListItems(ListName, _batchElement);
```

But, given that this xml element cannot have anything starting with a `\` it doesn't want to work.

I have tried HTML as well, even passing HTML through agility pack, and it just doesn't work either.

What is the proper method or field name or something to update that richtextbox?

do i need a `cdata`? or something?  I'm very confused, and the doco on MSDN isn't that great for this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it through an HTML encode, and it seems to work fine:

```
 private static string SetProperHTML(string sHtml)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);

        string input = sHtml;

        var test = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        test.LoadHtml(input);
        test.OptionOutputAsXml = false;
        test.OptionCheckSyntax = true;
        test.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        test.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
        test.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;

        test.Save(stringWriter);

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        return WebUtility.HtmlEncode(sb.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
    }
```

Also want to make sure that your `field` descriptor is setup properly:

```
_batchElement.InnerXml =
            string.Format(
                "<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field Name='Other_x0020_Items_x0020_of_x0020'>{0}</Field><Field Name='Overall_x0020_rating_x0020_of_x0'>{1}</Field><Field Name='Do_x0020_you_x0020_wish_x0020_to'>{2}</Field></Method>",
                SetProperHTML(add_Report_Details.Document.Body.InnerHtml),
                arrText,
                addreportwish);
```

it's a field like any other, no special child tags needed.  As long as the Sp2010 field on the form is setup for 100% full HTML, this should work.  There are other HTMLEncoders out there, which may be better than the `WebUtility` but, for the most part, this should work, given Agility Pack is fixing most of the HTML.